# Understanding F# tail-recursive

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

Recently, I'm learning F#.
I try to solve problem in different ways.
Like this:

```
(*

[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8] -> [(0,1,2);(3,4,5);(6,7,8)]

*)

//head-recursive
let rec toTriplet_v1 list=
    match list with
    | a::b::c::t -> (a,b,c)::(toTriplet_v1 t) 
    | _ -> []

//tail-recursive
let toTriplet_v2 list=
    let rec loop lst acc=
        match lst with
        | a::b::c::t -> loop t ((a,b,c)::acc)
        | _ -> acc
    loop list []

//tail-recursive(???)
let toTriplet_v3 list=
    let rec loop lst accfun=
        match lst with
        | a::b::c::t -> loop t (fun ls -> accfun ((a,b,c)::ls))
        | _ -> accfun []
    loop list (fun x -> x)

let funs = [toTriplet_v1; toTriplet_v2; toTriplet_v3];
funs |> List.map (fun x -> x [0..8]) |> List.iteri (fun i x -> printfn "V%d : %A" (i+1) x)
```

I thought the results of V2 and V3 should be the same.
But, I get the result below:

```
V1 : [(0, 1, 2); (3, 4, 5); (6, 7, 8)]
V2 : [(6, 7, 8); (3, 4, 5); (0, 1, 2)]
V3 : [(0, 1, 2); (3, 4, 5); (6, 7, 8)]
```

**Why the results of V2 and V3 are different?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

V2 uses standard **accumulating variable** to get tail recursion done:

```
loop ([0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8], []) ->
  loop ([3;4;5;6;7;8], [(0,1,2)]) ->
    loop ([6;7;8], [(3,4,5), (0,1,2)]) ->
      loop ([], [(6,7,8), (3,4,5), (0,1,2)]) ->
        [(6,7,8), (3,4,5), (0,1,2)]
```

V3 uses [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style), or in plain English, an **accumulating function**:

```
loop ([0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8], x->x) ->
  loop ([3;4;5;6;7;8], x->(0;1;2)::x) ->
    loop ([6;7;8], x->(3;4;5)::x) ->
      loop ([], x->(6,7,8)::x) ->
        [(6,7,8)]  // x->(6,7,8)::x applies to []
    ->
      [(3,4,5);(6,7,8)] // x->(3,4,5)::x applies to [(6,7,8)]
  ->
    [(0,1,2);(3,4,5);(6,7,8)] // x->(0,1,2)::x applies to [(3,4,5);(6,7,8)]
```

You can see the difference between accumulating variables and accumulating functions:

Using accumulating variables stops at the last call as the accumulating variable stores the answer. However, the accumulating function still does some **backtrack** work after the last call. It should be noticed that using accumulating functions is indeed tail recursive as the recursive call `loop t (fun ls -> accfun ((a,b,c)::ls))` is actually the **last** statement of this function.

Btw, the code you provided is a good example to show the concept tail recursive functions. One way to understand these sample code is to **work on small cases** as I did in the above two illustrations. After working on some small cases, you will understand the concept deeper.